# Dependency Analysis Warning for Javascript accordion collapsible. Assistance required

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, dependency-analysis

Built an html5 page with an accordion collapsible feature in javascript. In html5, it looks amazing, however after inserting the page and i try to run it in the simulator it does not work. The accordion collapsible feature is not displayed and i get these errors :

```
 - warning: no rule to process file
   '$(PROJECT_DIR)/donk/javascript/highlight.pack.js' of type
   sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
 - warning: no rule to process file
   '$(PROJECT_DIR)/donk/javascript/jquery-1.6.1.min.js' of type
   sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
 - warning: no rule to process file
   '$(PROJECT_DIR)/donk/javascript/jquery.accordion.js' of type
   sourcecode.javascript for architecture i386
```

Can anyone tell me what they mean and if they can be fixed to work?

Answer (score 4):

Go to "Targets" (in the "Groups & Files" pane on the left of Xcode), click the arrow next to it, then click the arrow next to your projects name, and drag the jquery.min.js (whatever your file) file*  from the "compile sources" folder to the "Copy Bundle Resources" folder. Do a "Build - clean all targets" from the main menu to build again and the problem should have been cured.